# Is it possible to scale the content of a QVBoxLayout in pyqt4?

Tags: pyqt4, scale

couldn't find anything with google or search. 
I have some QPushButtons and QLabels in a QVBoxLayout. Now I want them to scale down. Not only the text, the hole QButton and QLabel. Is that possible? If yes, can you please tell me how or post me a link to the doc. I'm pretty sure, that there must be a way. But I think I'm searching with the wrong words.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but perhaps you're looking for [QBoxLayout::addStretch](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qboxlayout.html#addStretch)?  By the way, I recommend using [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/designer-manual.html) to create your layout, PyQt4 comes with a tool called pyuic4 that creates the Python code for you.  [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/designer-manual.html) allows you to visually insert spacer items.